# Go Command Line Application Testing Tool

Tags: bash, go, automation, command-line-interface

I have a CLI developed in Go that automates the AWS devops platform. This app parses commands from a 'YML' and does build, deploy etc.

I want to test this at a high level through some automation process, other than writing bash scripts.  Is there a Framework or tools that I can use to automate this process?

Comment: Write [tests in Go itself](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/12)?

Comment: If you're wanting to test the AWS side, testing your go code with more go makes the most sense. If you're trying to test the CLI interface, what's wrong with bash scripts?